# How to give gradient color for IE8 browser?

Tags: css

I want to give a gradient color through CSS.Is there any way to give gradient for IE8.
 Presently following code working in IE10 but not working for IE8.

```
/* IE10 */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #00A3EF));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

/* Proposed W3C Markup */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);
```

Comment: How many times a week does this have to get asked without prior searching?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

[css3pie](http://css3pie.com/)

There are a few problems with it, and it can be a little slow if you are trying to do lots of stuff, but its the best way to use css3 in IE8 + 7.